# facing error when I try to install steam on my ubuntu22.04 arm64 cloud instance?

Tags: apt, 22.04, steam, cloud, oracle

I was trying to install Steam on my Oracle Cloud Ubuntu ARM64 instance, and I am encountering an error while running 'sudo apt update' on my Oracle OCI Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS with ARM64-based instance. I would like to obtain updated URLs for sources. list to use in my sources. list file. Can someone please provide me the sources.list repositories with the latest URLs?

Or does anyone know how to install Steam on my Ubuntu version?

I have tried various solutions from the Internet and Stack Overflow, but none of them have worked for me. I keep encountering errors such as 'failed to fetch' and '404 error: [example IP here]' and other stuff. I am not sure if these issues are caused because I am using an OCI instance or by some other problem. I have been struggling to solve this issue for the past two days but have not been able to find a solution. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance from anyone who has experienced a similar issue before.

Comment: This is something you need to research and or ask on the Steam site. Are you sure Steam works on ARM systems?

Answer (score 0):

Steam, and the vast majority (if not all, I haven't checked) of software (games) in Steam are built for i386 (32 bit Intel/AMD) and x86_64 (64 bit Intel/AMD) CPU architectures.

Your VM is an ARM64 CPU architecture. There's no build of Steam for that arch.  This will not work.